# Ghostdata in wifi communication between Android and Arduino

Tags: android, tcp, arduino, bufferedreader, printwriter

I set up an Arduino Nano as a TCP server. Then I wrote an Android app that is opening a socket and sending data, but it is not able to receive the answer from the server. The TCP server is receiving the message from the Android app but is getting sometimes more empty messages:

Android log:

```
05-27 04:08:04.673 7571-7571/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-27 04:08:04.768 7571-7571/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: onBtnClick(): gathering data from Buttons
05-27 04:08:04.768 7571-7571/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: onBtnClick(): data gathered: 00000000
05-27 04:08:04.843 7571-9973/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: startCom(): open socket(192.168.188.25,23598)
05-27 04:08:04.843 7571-9973/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: startCom(): sending data to device
05-27 04:08:04.848 7571-9973/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: startCom(): data sent to device (00000000)
05-27 04:08:04.848 7571-9973/com.livingroom.stefan.livinglight D/LivingLight: startCom(): socket closed
```

Log from Arduino:

```
ESP8266: init()
ESP8266: connected to wifi
ESP8266: TCP Server started
AT+CIFSR

+CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.188.25"
+CIFSR:STAMAC,"18:fe:34:a5:22:bb"

OK
got message:,9:00000000
0,CLOSED

set outputs: 00000000
got message:
got message:
got message:
got message:
got message:
```

To check if this problem is in my server or my Android app, I tried sending data to my Arduino from two additional devices. The C code on my Raspberry Pi and a program called "SocketTest3" worked fine. Both were sending data properly and receiving the acknowledge from the TCP server. That's why I guess the problem is in my Android code.

The strange thing is there is only from the android device a `0,CLOSED` behind the message.

I've found here some pieces of advice like flushing `PrintWriter` or waiting for `BufferedReader.ready()`. But neither of them led to a solution. The method `PrintWriter.checkError()` is false.

My Arduino code is:

```
void loop() {
  int client = esp8266.getId();
  if (client >= 0) {
    String msg = esp8266.readString();
    // receive data from serial buffer
    esp8266.sendData(client, "#\r\n");
    // acknowledge received data
    debug("got message:");
    debug(msg);
    // eg.:  ,9:01101001
    debug("\n");
    int start = msg.indexOf(':')+1;
    // gets index of : char
    if((msg.charAt(start)-48)>=0) {
      // checks if buffer contains data
      debug("set outputs: ");
      for(int i=0; i<N_LED; i++) {
        // for each LED (starts with PIN 2)
        digitalWrite((i+2),(msg.charAt(start+i)-48));
        debug(digitalRead(i+2));
        EEPROM.write(i,digitalRead(i+2));
      }
      debug("\n");
    }
    esp8266.closeConnection(client);
  }
} //end loop
```

String preparation `txData`:

```
public void onBtnClick() {
    txData = "";
    if(tbAllOff.isChecked()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBtnClick, allOff");
        txData = "00000000";
    } else if(tbAllOn.isChecked()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBtnclick, allOn");
        txData = "11111111";
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBtnClick, gathering data from Buttons");
        for (int i=0; i<tbList.length; i++) {
            txData += (tbList[i].isChecked())?1:0;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onBtnClick, data gathered: " + txData);
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        new Client().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    else
        new Client().execute();
    txt1.setText(rxData);
}
```

The socket part from my Android app is:

```
private class Client extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  protected Void doInBackground(String[] params) {
    try {
      Log.d(TAG,"AsyncTask.doInBackground(): send data: "+ txData);
      rxData = startCom();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      rxData = "IOException: " + e;
      Log.e(TAG,rxData);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private String startCom() throws IOException {
    ipAddress = "192.168.188.25";
    portNumber = 23598;
    Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
    Log.d(TAG,"startCom(): open socket(" + ipAddress + "," + portNumber + ")");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
    Log.d(TAG,"startCom(): sending data to device");
    output.println(txData);
    output.close();
    Log.d(TAG,"startCom(): data sent to device (" + txData + ")");
    String in = "#";
    if(input.ready()) {
      in = input.readLine();
      Log.d(TAG, "startCom(): data received: " + in);
    }
    socket.close();
    Log.d(TAG,"startCom(): socket closed");
    return in;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is sendData? And what does it contain? Why a function and variable with the same name? Unreadable code.

Comment: You are also receiving data in sendData(). So wrong function name i would say.

Comment: You are right. But changing the variable and method name didn't solve the issue. `rxData` and `txData` are `String`

Comment: We still dont know what you send. You omit basic info.

Comment: `and receiving the acknowledge from the TCP server`. What do you consider to be the acknowledgement?

Comment: I added preparation of  `txData`. For now i just send a `#` sign, later i will send information like actual output setup. You can see this in the arduino code line `esp8266.sendData(client, "#\r\n");` .

Comment: `output.close();` change that to `output.flush();`.

Comment: It helped a little bit. But still one out of ten times i get that empty String. And i still don't receive any data on Android.

Comment: It is unclear where you get an empty string. Please be precise. Why do you use execute on executor? You will get problems if you tap quickly. Try without.

Comment: I used the `new Client().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` because in one of the other threads someone was told, that there could be a problem, if you use `new Client().execute()` on API less then 15. I already changed back to only use `new Client().execute()` and set my minAPI on 17. I get an empty string on my Arduino, view my posted Arduino log.

Comment: Oh you get an empty string on Anduino. Good you told us. But what did you sent? When  third option we do not know what you send. You should write a predetermined string only. Reproducable code.

Comment: Well, in my question i already told `I set up an Arduino Nano as a TCP server` later in that paragraph i told `The TCP server is receiving the message from the Android app but is getting sometimes more empty messages`. After this, i presented the log from my Android app and Arduino where you can see what Android is sending (by hitting the button once) and what the Arduino is receiving from this one message. About in the middle of my question you will find the source code where i exactly show how the message-string is created. its always a combination of eight ones or zeros e.g. `01010101`.

Comment: As if i after 12 hours still remember what all happens in your code. You could take the effort to write who is receiving empty stings instead of forcing your helpers to read your whole post for it.

Comment: `if(input.ready()) `  remove that.